execute fixtures from skipped tests in pytest
I have a large selenium suite that uses session fixtures to establish setting up data within the web application being tested (e.g. user created aggregates; locations, people, statuses, etc). So for any test that requires the use of one of the aggregates, it uses one of these fixtures.  Each of the fixtures handles walking through the application and creating the aggregate.  (the suite always assumes the database has been wiped clean)
This makes it possible to run any subset of tests (without having to run the whole suite) and dependencies on aggregates is not an issue.
A very simple example of a test module would look something like this:
test_a(fixture_a)
test_b(fixture_b)
test_c(fixture_a)

The suite is designed to execute the modules in order.
module_1
module_2
module_3

The suite is also tagged in such a way that allows us to run the test in order starting at specified point.
Example:
We can start the suite at module_2.  All the tests from that point will run in the normal order, just skipping module_1.
Problem:
When we skip tests, the fixtures aren't executed in the same order. (naturally) In some cases, we might not execute a fixture at all.
If we skip test_a, fixture_a won't get executed until test_c.  I'd like to be able to skip test_a but still have the option to have fixture_a execute.
I want to be able to skip tests, but still execute the fixtures in their typical order.
How might this be possible?

Can't you just execute all of the fixtures in the desired order before the suite starts?

Statically, I believe I could. I couldn't see a way to do that dynamically.  For instance, if I decide to skip modules 1 & 2 this time but 1,2,&3 next time.

I guess I don't follow. Just always run all fixtures before the suite starts. You are asking for a non-dynamic solution because you always want to run them even if you skip tests that would otherwise run them.

adding autouse=True to your fixtures can be beneficial if you want them to be executed anyway

The problem with that is the order of events.  I want to preserve the order of fixtures running.

Where do you store your fixtures? If you store them in conftest.py with autouse=True then execution order will be from first to last always.
